# Search With Filters from Other Tables

Tags: laravel

I try to build a search query with different params but some of the filters columns comes from other tables who are in relation with another table , i don't know how to achieve that

For exemple the column "compet_id" comes from my table Rencontre.

In my table RencontreOfficiel i have rencontre_id to make the relation with "Rencontre"

I'm not sure if my clear it's a little bit difficult to explain ; hope someone could see and help .

here my controller :

```
$query = RencontreOfficiel::query();

        $filters = [
        'compet_id' => 'compet_id',
        'structure_id' => 'structure_id',
        'catg_compet_id' => 'dt_rencontre',
        'fonction_id' => 'dt_rencontre',
        'bareme_id' => 'bareme_id',
        'dt_min_rencontre' => 'dt_rencontre',
        'dt_max_rencontre' => 'dt_rencontre',

        ];

        $dt_min = $request->input('dt_rencontre_min');
        $dt_max = $request->input('dt_rencontre_max');

        foreach ($filters as $key => $column) {
            $query->when($request->{$key}, function ($query, $value) use ($column , $dt_min , $dt_max) {
                $query->where($column, $value)->orWhereBetween('dt_rencontre' , [$dt_min , $dt_max]);
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereHas` and `with` keyword in `Eloquent` search.

for example you have `Blog` method that connected to `User` model. every Blog send by user . If you want to have search in User according to his blogs you can use this :

```
 $user = User::where(function($query){
               $query->where('age','>=',18);

            })->whereHas('blogs', function ($query){

                    $query->where('text', 'LIKE', '%game%');

            });
```

In this code `blogs` in `whereHas` method is name of Eloquent method in `User` model.

Result : this code return users older than 18 years that have blogs with title like game.